# Automatically fill and submit the numbers

Tags: javascript

I need to fill table with numbers automatically. And for this cause I'm using this bookmarklet:

```
javascript:var crn=[num1,num2...];
  for(var i=0;i<crn.length;i++){
   var d=document.getElementById("crn_id"+(i+1));
   d.value=crn[i];
}
void(0);
```

It works but I need to click this submit button :

```
<input type="submit" name="REG_BTN" value="Submit Changes">
```

I tried to use this code:

```
javascript: var document.getElementsByTagName('submit')[0].click();
```

But it doesn't work.There is a sample of the website that I m trying to fill: (https://web.itu.edu.tr/durgunor/crn.html)

How can I fill the table and submit it with unified code?

Comment: Add your reproducable issue snippet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a form, try this

```
javascript:(function() {
  ["num1","num2"].forEach((crn,i) => document.getElementById(`crn_id${(i+1)}`).value=crn;
  document.form.submit()})()
```

Comment: This error occurs : Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: It doesn't work but there is a sample of website that I m trying to fill https://web.itu.edu.tr/durgunor/crn.html